# Does the Gmail REST API have access to label colors?

Tags: gmail-api

Is it possible to get label colors through the new Gmail REST API? Many of our users color code their emails and it would be great to be able to carry that color coding over to our applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't as per the docs a label consists of:

```
{
 "id": string,
 "name": string,
 "messageListVisibility": string,
 "labelListVisibility": string,
 "type": string
}
```

see: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels

That does seem like a useful enhancement though.

Answer (score -1):

Python below

```py
def MakeLabel(label_name, mlv='show', llv='labelShow'):
    """Create Label object.

    Args:
        label_name: The name of the Label.
        mlv: Message list visibility, show/hide.
        llv: Label list visibility, labelShow/labelHide.

    Returns:
        Created Label.
    """
    bg_red_color = {
        'backgroundColor': '#cc3a21',
        'textColor': '#000000',
    }
        
    label = {
        'color':                 bg_red_color, 
        'messageListVisibility': mlv,
        'name':                  label_name,
        'labelListVisibility':   llv,
    }
    return label
```

Label object definition: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.labels#Label

If you need more colors see: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.labels#Color